# Proof that a set is convex using parametrization and acceleration

Tags: differential-geometry

Let's say we have a set $S$ defined as follows:

$$S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x^2+4y^2\leq1\}$$

and we must proof that it is convex. I know the regular proof, using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and other nifty things, but it wasn't very elegant and I wanted to do better. (it is probably wrong for some basic reason, though.)

First, I found a parametric equation for the ellipse $x^2+4y^2=1$, which is$(\cos t,\frac12\sin t)$. I differentiated it twice to obtain acceleration and I remembered a topic from Calculus I, about acceleration being related to concavity. I figured, if acceleration is never $\vec0$, then it can't change signs and the concavity of the curve always stays the same.

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\cos t,\frac12\sin t)=(-\sin t, \frac12\cos t)$$
and
$$\frac{d}{dx}(-\sin t, \frac12\cos t)=(-\cos t,-\frac12\sin t)$$
which is the acceleration vector. $\cos t$ and $\frac12\sin t$ can't both equal $0$ for the same $t$, so I concluded that the concavity doesn't change. Since the concavity doesn't change, the set must be convex.

Comment: What do you mean by the sign of a pair of numbers? You can work this line of reasoning into a proof, but I think there are more straightforward proofs. for example, you can show tht $n((x,y)) = \sqrt{x^2+4y^2}$ is a norm, and norms are always convex (as functions), hence $S = \{(x,y) | n((x,y)) \le 1 \}$ is convex.

Comment: That's where I thought the proof would fall apart, it really doesn't make much sense now that I think about it. The norm proof seems interesting, where could I read more about it? My Calculus book doesn't offer much about convex sets, but I need to study them anyway

Comment: Convexity is covered in many books, for example,  "Convex Optimization" by Boyd & Vandenberghe. A classic (although not as easy a read) reference is "Convex Analysis" by Rockafellar. However, it is straightforward to show that a norm is convex just from the properties of a norm. It is also straightforward to show that if $f$ is convex, then the sets $\{x | f(x) \le \alpha \}$ are convex.